# Faster Alternative to Aggregating and Pivoting a Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table, aggregate

I have a dataframe of population data that looks like this, where every row is the population of a county taken at a specific date

```
County Date     Population
Alba   1900-1-1   1094
Alba   1900-2-1   1107
Alba   1900-3-1   1120
Belfor 1900-1-1   9756
Belfor 1900-3-1   9976
...
```

I want to get a dataframe where the index is the year, the columns are the county names, and the values are the average population in a given year.

This is what my code looks like currently

```
#year
df['Year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['date']).year.fillna(0).astype(int)

##create aggregation on year, county of population
new_df =  df.groupby(['Year','County']).mean()
#turn county into column
new_df.reset_index(level=1, inplace=True)
##pivot dataframe
new_df.pivot(columns='Country',values='Population')
```

This has proven extraordinarily slow since there are several entries per year for hundreds of years. What can I do instead to make this run faster

Comment: Use `df.pivot_table(index='Year', columns='County', values='Population')`, default aggregation is `mean`, so `aggfunc` is not necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try `crosstab` to create a cross tabulation:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
pd.crosstab(df['Date'].dt.year, df['County'], df['Population'], aggfunc='mean')
```

Alternatively you can use `pivot_table`:

```
df.pivot_table(index=df['Date'].dt.year, columns='County', values='Population', aggfunc='mean')
```

Result:

```
County  Alba  Belfor
Date                
1900    1107    9866
```

Comment: What is the performance of cross_tab and pivot_table compared to aggregate + pivot. I would assume pivot_table is similar internally. Is cross tab much faster?

Comment: @knowads I think performance wise here `crosstab` is equivalent to using `pivot_table`..

Comment: Update: Did a timing test and Crosstab was slightly faster on this particular dataset but they were close enough that both would have been fine

Comment: @knowads Thanks for testing..That's good to know :)